# jQuery animate array skip to last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate an array of images using Jquery. When I have one element in the array it works fine but when I have more then one element it just animates the last element of the array.

I set the `src` of the `img` tag and move it to the right. The `moveRight` function move the image to the right and call `moveLeft` to move it to the left. The `moveLeft` function moves the image to the left and fade it.

```
$.each(imageArray, function (i, val) {
    $("#b").attr("src", imageArray[i].src);
    moveRight();
}

function moveRight(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=500"}, 2000, moveLeft)
}

function moveLeft(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=500"}, 2000,fade)
}
```

Is there a way each image can be moved right and left / or just left or right instead of having the last one moving only. I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `$.each()` loops immediately. All you're doing is changing the source of the image without delay so it only seems like its jumping to the last image when in reality its just changing the source so fast you don't see it. Also why are you changing the image source, but also animating the whole thing left?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: What's your desired functionality? Does it switch on a set time? Does it respond to the user click?

Comment: I can't really get what you are trying to do. $("#b") is an <img>? Do you want to see all your Images at once moving or set one src, animate and change to the next src and animate?

Comment: The desired functionality is to animate an array of image one by one and play a  sound while animate each of them as part of a game.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing you can do is to use a recursive method.  Here is an example (*[check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/6aqzugba/)*):

```
var MyApp = {

    Items: {

        Elements: $('div'),

        Loaded: 0

    },

    Start: function(){
        if( this.Items.Elements.length == this.Items.Loaded ) return; // return.. or play a sound, then return to stop iterations

        this.Items.Elements.eq(this.Items.Loaded).animate({ left: '50%' }, { 
            duration: 1000,
            complete: function(){
                MyApp.Items.Loaded++;
                MyApp.Start();
            }
        });
    }

};

$(function(){ 
    MyApp.Start();
});
```

It's an example but you can do it easily by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example of what you're trying to achieve. From here you can try and animate the transition, switch it so buttons activate a left/right change. I would suggest playing around with this until you comfortable with the basic functionality. From there you can look into plugins/libraries that can help you. http://jsfiddle.net/306Lqov5/1/

**HTML**

```
<img id="b" src="http://placehold.it/100/100&text=Image 1" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var images = [
    'http://placehold.it/100/100&text=Image 1',
    'http://placehold.it/100/100&text=Image 2',
    'http://placehold.it/100/100&text=Image 3',
    'http://placehold.it/100/100&text=Image 4'
];

var index = 1, //start at one since we have the first image in by defualt
    img = $('#b');

setInterval(function(){
    img.attr('src', images[index]);
    index++; //index = index + 1;

    if (index == images.length){ //if we've reached the length of the array reset to zero
        index = 0;
    }
},2000); //switch ever 2 seconds
```

Comment: just use `index = (index + 1) % images.length`

Comment: @royhowie The goal was to give an accessible solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this variant: http://jsbin.com/xezetuboye/1/edit?html,js,output ?

```
var arr = [
  'http://e404.pw/pictures/evernote-logo.png',
  'http://e404.pw/pictures/font-face.png',
  'http://e404.pw/pictures/html-coder.jpg'
];
var count = 0;

function setImg(){
  if(arr.length <= count){ return; }
    $("#b").attr("src", arr[count]);
    moveRight();
    count++;
}

function moveRight(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=500"}, 2000, moveLeft);
}

function moveLeft(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=500"}, 2000, setImg);

}

setImg();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.queue()`. Note, if changing `src` of same `img` element , would have to wait until each image loaded.

```js
var imageArray = [
  "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats",
  "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals",
  "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics",
  "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature"
];

var b = $("#b");

var cycle = function cycle() {
  return b.queue("slide", $.map(imageArray, function(val, i) {
    return function(next) {
      $(this).fadeOut(50).attr("src", val);
      this.onload = function() {
        return $(this).fadeIn(50, function() {
          return moveRight.call(this).then(function() {
            return moveLeft.call(this)
          }).then(next);
        });            
      }
    }
  })).dequeue("slide");
};

function moveRight() {
  return $(this).animate({
    left: "500"
  }, 2000).promise()
}

function moveLeft() {
  return $(this).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 2000).promise()
}

var infiniteCycle = function infiniteCycle() {
  return cycle().promise("slide").then(infiniteCycle)
};

infiniteCycle();
```

```css
#b {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<img id="b" />
```